# reading csv using atof() with c++

Tags: c++, arrays, csv

I was stuck in this problem, I tried to read the datas from my csv file.

I will put my output and source code below.

As you can see,I'm printing the value of tmp[i] first and then I use another array to store the value in column tmp[i].

But the outputs are wrong. It's value should be the same as tmp[i].

Hoping someone can help me deal with this.

```
output:
69
26
54
3
69
54.1442
54.6054
54.1772
```

```
double stockp1[1000];
double stockp2[1000];
double stockp3[1000];
double stockp4[1000];
 int c=0,d=0,e=0,f=0;
 while (getline(inFile, line))
    {
        vector<string> a = _csv(line);
        stockp1[c++] = atof(a[tmp[0]].c_str());
        stockp2[d++] = atof(a[tmp[1]].c_str());
        stockp3[f++] = atof(a[tmp[2]].c_str());
        stockp4[e++] = atof(a[tmp[3]].c_str());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << tmp[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << stockp1[0] << endl;
    cout << stockp2[0] << endl;
    cout << stockp3[0] << endl;
    cout << stockp4[0] << endl;
}

vector<string> _csv(string s)
{
    vector<string> arr;
    istringstream delim(s);
    string token;
    int c = 0;
    while (getline(delim, token, ','))
    {
        arr.push_back(token);
        c++;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] to show how `stockp1`, etc. are declared?

Comment: I update my code, I just simply declared ```double stockp1[1000]```

Comment: Why fixed-length when you're already using `std::vector` elsewhere? This really should be `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` as your overall structure. Having a bunch of unrelated arrays is a huge mess.

Comment: THX UR HELP. I use vector to store it. and the output is correct.

Comment: use `stof(a[tmp[2]])` instead of `atof(a[tmp[2]].c_str());`